# Whatsapp: iPhone to Android: 0 messages restored

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, ios, chat, chat-history

I backed up my iphone's whatsapp chat history and tried to restore it to my Samsung galaxy s6 when install whatsapp. I've tried this countless times and always got 0 messages restored (also making sure to uninstall the app every time I try again). I even rebooted the phone, but none of it helped. and yes, I redid the icloud backup that time.

Comment: I think android cannot retrieve your messages from iCloud (as iCloud belongs to Apple). I don't know whether whatsapp (Apple) have an option to backup messages to google drive. Whatsapp (Android) can only retrieve backups from Google drive and Local backup

Comment: I have also experienced the same thing, transferring whatsapp chat history from  Symbian to Android. It is not possible, because of difference in file format.

Comment: The same way you can't play a save game file from an Xbox on a PlayStation, you can't use iCloud backups on Android.

Comment: I've heard of Wazzap Migrator, its free for the text messages but costs money for the media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Wazzap Migrator was the answer, it costs money to restore media as well.

To extract the conversations + media:
1. Download the free backup extractor http://www.wazzapmigrator.com/faq/free-itunes-backup-extractor-windows.
2. Open it and select your iPhone (it should be plugged in to your PC of course).
3. Go into advanced and check "Applications".
4. Click "extract selected files".
5. The conversations should be stored in "Desktop\Extracted from backup for WazzapMigrator\Applications\net.whatsapp.WhatsApp\Documents\ChatStorage.sqlite"
and the media folder in "Desktop\Extracted from backup for WazzapMigrator\Applications\net.whatsapp.WhatsApp\Library".

Make sure your have to paid version of Wazzap Migrator installed on your android phone. (Or you will only be able to restore conversations without media).

To put the extracted conversations + media on your android device to select in Wazzap Migrator:
1. Plug your android phone into your PC.
2. Go into your phone's internal storage via Explorer.
3. Create a folder, named anything, and drag `ChatStorage.sqlite` and the media folder into it.

To restore:
1. Install Whatsapp.
2. Open Wazzap Migrator.
3. Select your conversation file and media folder manually.
4. Start the conversion.
5. Reinstall and start Whatsapp.
6. If it detects a backup in your devices storage, tap restore.
7. That's it.

Keep in mind that my memory of what I did is sort of fuzzy. You should know what to do, however.

Source: http://www.wazzapmigrator.com/faq/how-import-media